# сбросить переменную i в цикле for

Tags: javascript

возможно ли сбросить переменную в цикле for в исходное значение? Например:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if (array[i]==array[i+1]){
  array.splice(i,i+1)
  i=0 
 }
}
```

Comment: Нужно избегать потенциальной опасности на выходе получить бесконечный цикл) И искать другое решение для той же задачи.

Comment: Я через рекурсию сделал, хотя ей же точно так же можно заспамить стек наверное)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bозможно, но не нужно.

```js
function removeDup(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(removeDup([1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5]));
```